# is it "I have traveled or I travel"

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-simple

which is correct?

> This is the third time I have traveled to Italy this year.

or

> This is the third time I travel to Italy this year.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *This is the third time I have traveled to Italy this year* - FINE
>    2: *This is the third time I travel to Italy this year* - SYNTACTICALLY INVALID

Note that I'm assuming the context is that the speaker *is in Italy* at time of speaking, in which case I suggest no native speaker would ever use #2 above. But you *might* sometimes hear it said ***before*** the speaker travels to Italy (for the third time in a year), as a "cut-down, syntactically questionable" (but *idiomatic*) version of...

> 3: *This **will be** the third time I [**will**] travel to Italy this year* - acceptable, but "wordy"

English doesn't have a natural way<sup>1</sup> of using a *continuous* verb form in this type of construction for this sense, if the speaker is ***currently*** travelling to Italy...

> 4: ?? *This is the third time I **am traveling** to Italy this year* - grammatical, but non-idiomatic

To convey *that* sense, we'd normally use a rather different structure...

> 5: *This is **my third time of traveling** to Italy this year* - grammatical & idiomatic
>    ...or...
>    6: *This is **my third trip** to Italy this year* - what most people would actually say

---

<sup>1</sup> It's also quite natural to say...

7: ***I'm traveling*** to Italy for the third time this year

...but again, this is a significantly different sentence structure to OP's original.

Comment: There is another one: "This is the third time I am having to travel to ..." Well, this sounds like someone's making me go there. :)

Comment: More idiomatically, perhaps, *This is **my** third time **of** having to travel to ...* for the "Present" sense. Maybe I just don't like your version because it smacks of "Indian English" - it seems fine as a "Present Perfect = Past" tense usage: *This is the third time **I've had** to travel to ...*